# create-admin error: There in no appbuilder var on your package, you can use appbuilder parameter to config

Tags: python, flask-appbuilder

I am facing issue with the command: fabmanager create-admin
Here is a sequence of steps I performed:

I followed all the installation steps on my Windows 10 machine to install flask_appbuilder. Then I downloaded the skeleton app using the command : "fabmanager create-app". But when i issue the command: "fabmanager create-admin" from the newly created skeleton app dir, it throws the error:

"There in no appbuilder var on your package, you can use appbuilder parameter to config".

I checked the app/**init**.py file, it does contain the appbuilder var. Here is dump of that file:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from flask_appbuilder import SQLA, AppBuilder

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLA(app)
appbuilder = AppBuilder(app, db.session)

from app import views
```

I tried issuing the same command with admin rights, but no success.
As per the documentation, if we try to use a different name (other that appbuilder), we can make use of --appbuilder option to configure that, but in my case I am not doing any such thing.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I could come up with was shifting python version.
Earlier I was using Python 3.6.3 that came bundled with Anaconda.
But on my team-mate's suggestion, I installed stand alone python 3.6.0, and it worked!

Not an ideal solution to the problem here, just a workaround for someone facing similar problem.